# Liquibase precondition sql check returns incorrect result

Tags: postgresql, liquibase, liquibase-maven-plugin

I've been struggling to troubleshoot and fix this problem for few days now. The liquibase changeset are not running due to sql check.

```
-- changeset ryanjan:1 context:staging
-- preconditions onFail:MARK_RAN onError:MARK_RAN
-- precondition-sql-check expectedResult:1 SELECT COUNT(column_name) FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name='position' and column_name='initial';
ALTER TABLE public.position
  RENAME COLUMN initial TO shortname;

-- changeset ryanjan:2 context:staging
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS position_shortname_unique ON public.position (shortname);
```

The first changeset is not executing for unknown reason.

**Troubleshooting performed**

1. I logged in to the staging DB cli and connected to the same user.
2. Executed the same `SELECT` query and got result **1**.
3. Reviewed the `public.position` table and column `initial` exists.

At this moment, I can no longer think of what's wrong with the query. I am able to perform the query via CLI with the same account so permission grant is not a problem (I think). Removing the `precondition-sql-check` will surely execute the changeset.

PostgreSQL version 13.1

Comment: if you run an updateSQL command, what does it outputs (around that changeset)?  Also, can you have a quick look over table databasechangelog and see if that changeset is there (expecting to not be there but just to be sure)? Also, can you remove the blank space on each line between "--" and the first characters of the formatted sql "code"?